# How can I weave aspect code into existing class files within JARs?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am new to aspectj and I have one doubt whether we can inject the code before the function that exists in the jar file using aspectj.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can weave aspect code into third-party class files or JARs. There are two ways to achieve that:

- Binary weaving: Use the AspectJ compiler *ajc* in order to apply your aspects upon class files in an existing JAR. For that purpose, put the JAR on the compiler's *inpath*. After compilation you can re-package the newly woven class files into a new JAR which then you can deploy and use instead of the original one.
- Load-time weaving (LTW): Start the JVM with the AspectJ weaving agent via command line option `-javaagent:pathto/aspectjweaver.jar` in order to achieve aspect weaving during classloading. This way you sacrifice some start-up time, but do not need to create a modified JAR file. Everything happens dynamically.

And now please read some [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/).

Comment: How can I do this using eclipse?

Comment: Go figure. ;-) That was not part of the original question, but you can do it, I promise. I have answered several of your very vague questions now, but instead of always asking new ones you could start reviewing the existing answers and accept and upvote them (ever heard about etiquette?). Maybe then it would be more fun to invest time in figuring out what you actually want to know and then answer.